# Do you keep original Laravel migrations when they become obsolete?

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

We have quite a few migrations in our of our Laravel application. Now we are making some changes that make certain tables obsolete and where we actually want to rename certain columns in some tables.

What is the best practice for performing that change?

1. Do you keep the old migrations the way they are and try to add a migration that alters all affected tables and columns accordingly?
2. Can you just update the old migrations and delete the ones for tables that are no longer needed?

I'm sure there are pro's and con's to both approaches.

Comment: The purpose of migrations is to provide a path for multiple distinct databases to remain consistent with the application's schema over time but that isn't always necessary. For example, if you're the only developer or you're not yet in production, it's not important to have a full history of every schema change. Personally, I regularly consolidate my migrations when it's appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally believe that the first approach is the best practice and here is why. We know that the migrations are stored into the migrations table when you migrate which is why they are only migrated once. Now if you update one and try to migrate you will not get anything because this migration has already been done. As for deleting a migration it is really not recommended since you might end up changing servers or needing a fresh DB and that might cause you issues.

It is very important to maintain the flow of the migrations. Even if that means adding and dropping tables. Off course this will make your migrations folder bigger and clunkier but it is the safe choice. You can avoid that by using proper project planning and trying to minimize the number of migrations.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your answer. Does that mean that you have to change table / column names back in the `down()` method of the migrations or will those stay empty?

Comment: @molerat the purpose of the down method is to reverse the migration. Usually it is best practice to reverse what you did in the up method even if you know that you will never do that reverse. So it is preferable that you never keep them empty

Answer (score 4):

To make those changes, create a new migration which drops the old tables and renames the fields which need renaming.

For point 2, it is alright to update old migrations whilst developing locally. And **only** if the migration has not been ran on a production server.

This generally tends to be acceptable during the the initial development stage of a project.

Running the `php artisan migrate` on a production server with an amended migration file will not update the database (as the database logs performed migrations).

As @khaldoun-nd mentioned, its better to maintain the flow of migrations, only creating them when needed and deploying once you know your intended code is working well.